# Using react-hook-form with material-ui (mui): How do I use the required flag on inputs in with the rules validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-forms` for our applications form functionality/validation, and using MUI/Material-UI for our component library. MUI will automatically append the `*` onto input labels if the input has the `required` attribute set, however when we add the `required` attribute to our inputs the HTML5 form validation takes precedence over `react-hook-form`'s validation using the `rules` prop.

How can we use both of these concepts together so that MUI appends the `*` on required fields, but `react-hook-form`'s `rules` validation is applied rather than HTML5's validation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all of your inputs in the `form` tag to ignore HTML5 validation, you can simply add the `noValidation` attribute to the `form` tag that wraps the inputs. This will disable HTML5 validation from being ran, and will allow `react-hook-form` to run the `rules` validation.

Note: If you have the `required` attribute added to an input, but you do not have `rules` added to the Controller for the input then your input will not be validated as being required.

Comment: How can we do it with FormProvider and Controller? Like if I add required attribute in [these Controller fields](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb).

Comment: @UmarMunir The code you shared looks to behave the same as this answer. The `FormProvider` appears to wrap your two components with a `form` that has `novalidation` added.

Comment: Yes, I was able to achieve this so I updated the code.